# Show/Hide div inside DataList

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to toggle Gridview on LinkButton.Both are inside Datalist ItemTemplate.Kindly help

```
   <asp:DataList ID="dl_newtabs" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
    <ItemTemplate>
   <div class="solution_footer">
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_tabnew" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("service_name") %>'
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("service_name")  %>' OnClick="lnk_tabnewclick"  CssClass="toggdiv"></asp:LinkButton>
   </div>
    <div id="Div1" style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll; float: left;   width: 100%;" >
   <asp:Gridview id ="grddesc" runat="server">
  </asp:Gridview>
  </div>

   </asp:DataList>
```

This is what i so far done, On Click of LinkButton.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".Div1").hide();
        $(".solution_footer").click(function () {
            $(this).nextAll('div[class="Div1"]').eq(0).slideToggle(100);
        });
    });
```

[image]

Comment: ... what's wrong with what you have at the moment? Does that work? You've not really [asked a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: He wants to toggle gridview on link button's click

Comment: using jQuery you can try  $( "#Div1" ).toggle();

Comment: So what error or problem are you getting here ?

Comment: I had updated my Questions. I need to toggle Gridview Content on Click of LinkButton.

Comment: I had tried, .toggle(), .hide() nothing working for me.

Comment: @ManishGoswami is javascript event firing? I guess its not..

Comment: yes event fired, but it again display both like in above.

Answer (score 0):

**JS:**

```
function lnk_tabnewclick(){
    $('#grddesc').toggleClass('hidden');
}
```

I have just used the on click event that you are already firing `on click` here... Change if required.

**CSS:**

```
.hidden{ display: none }
```

**HTML:**

```
   <asp:Gridview id ="grddesc" runat="server" class="hidden">
```

Or, if you want to apply the show/hide to the containing `<div>`:

```
<div id="Div1" class="hidden"></div>
```

If you want the gridview hidden first then keep the class there. If not, remove the hidden class and it will applied on click.

Comment: Have you attached the hidden class to the gridview or the div?

Comment: Yes i had done as you said,but still not working On Click of same linkbutton i am binding same gridview I had uploaded image in my questions

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
<div id="Div1" style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll; float: left;   width: 100%;" >
```

Div1 is not a "class" its "id"

Try changing it to

```
<div class="Div1" style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll; float: left;   width: 100%;" >

$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".Div1").hide();
        $(".solution_footer").click(function () {
            $(this).nextAll('div[class="Div1"]').eq(0).slideToggle(100);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yes ii Did still not working, Is it because of i am binding  gridview on LinkButton Click ?

Comment: why do u want to do it using datalist. I clearly can see there are only two items in your datalist. Just create separate controls and you can manage it more easily.

Comment: Yes but this two controls poppulate as per the services assgined to users, Eg: ABC user is assigned for cancellation then only Cancellation will be seen. There are various other servies too like Reissue, etc etc